# Double precision: When is near-zero considered zero?

Tags: limits, machine-precision

I came across an issue in code whereby I noticed the standard deviation, $\sigma$, of a set of constant values of e.g. 0.33333333 = 1/3 was not equal to zero.  Rather,  $\sigma$ was some small near-zero value.

Below is an example Excel spreadsheet I learned could easily replicate the issue after converting 1/3 to decimal form, and then calculating sigma.

Is there a generic mathematical function that one can use perhaps involving modulo, floor, ceiling, etc., on this value of  $\sigma$ that will identify it as effectively being zero?  Does one need to estimate the machine precision, $\epsilon$, for the code one is working with?

[image]

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-calculates-a-non-zero-standard-deviation/4b08dc69-23b6-4686-8134-2a018a746a3c
https://floating-point-gui.de/

Just round it to (say) 15 fractional digits with ROUND()

Comment: Thanks - did you see that the issue's not specific to Excel, but rather working with float or double precision?  Repeating decimal values also don't help either, since there's no final 3 in 0.333333333....   But overall, I found a lot on the fact that it's more due to the fact that single and double precision are not infinite precision.   I need to look up some machine-precision code perhaps in Numerical Recipes.

Comment: The second link is about floating point issues in general.

Comment: These kind of floating point issues are common. What's your specific goal in identifying $\sigma = 0$? If you have exact rational values for all of your values, you could find the exact form of the variance by performing rational arithmetic. I don't know if Excel is capable of this but you could use e.g. Sympy in python if you are familiar with that.  But if your purpose isn't to do any exact arithmetic then just rounding the result should work fine.

Comment: The approach I've taken in cases like this is that when a set of data will all be equal to the same constant value, I don't do arithmetic on them. The mean would be a copy of one of the values and standard deviation would be set to zero explicitly. If I'm not anticipating constant data then it's because I'm almost certainly **not** going to get constant data and therefore the s.d. is just whatever the computation says it is (which won't be zero). There are a lot of difficulties due to the finite precision of floating-point numbers, but I don't see this as one of them.

Comment: I did try using e.g. Round(x, 15) but I think something like 15 is too arbitrary.  (I am using .NET's C# for code).  @David K, I like your idea, since it could be done using an Invariance(x) function, where you simply check if all vector elements are the same, and if so return a boolean yes and then skip that zero $\sigma$.   I am skipping over vectors that have zero $\sigma$ but can think of ways to exploit zero $\sigma$ for classification analysis, since no one is really taught to hunt for features whose values are invariant within one class label, and then non-zero variance in another.